# MATLAB: Referencing an element in a structure

Tags: matlab, structure, switch-statement

I am trying to reference an element buried within a structure that I did not create (hence I don't know the exact way in which it was built).

Having loaded the structure, if I type:

```
dataFile.RECORDINGS.eye
```

I receive the following output:

```
ans =

    2


ans =

    2
```

Both of those variables will always be the same, but they could be at any time 1, 2 or 3. What I'd like to do is check with a switch statement which looks like this:

```
switch dataFile.RECORDINGS.eye
    case {1, 2}
        % action A
    case 3
        % action B
end
```

Of course, the above throws up an error because 'case' cannot check whether dataFile.RECORDINGS.eye contains a given value since there are two elements stored under that address. So, my question is: how do I reference just one of the elements? I thought it would be as simple as replacing the first line with:

```
switch dataFile.RECORDINGS.eye(1)
```

...But, this gives the error:

```
??? Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by more reference blocks is an error.
```

Similarly, I can't access the element like this:

```
switch dataFile.RECORDINGS.eye.1
```

...As I get the following error:

```
??? Dot name reference on non-scalar structure.
```

Comment: What does `class(dataFile.RECORDINGS.eye)` tell you?

Comment: ??? Error using ==> class
The CLASS function must be called from a class constructor.

However, class(dataFile.RECORDINGS) reports 'struct'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the values are really always the same, you  can try the following to get a scalar that can be used in the  switch command:

```
unique([dataFile.RECORDINGS.eye])
```

By the way, did you try to index RECORDINGS, i.e.,

```
dataFile.RECORDINGS(1).eye   
dataFile.RECORDINGS(2).eye
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the issue was the indexing of RECORDINGS, although the 'unique' function is useful to know as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps instead of `eye` having multiple elements, you have multiple elements of `RECORDINGS` that each have a single value of `eye`? You might want `dataFile.RECORDINGS(1).eye` or `dataFile.RECORDINGS(2).eye`.